# how to set beforsend option in wordpress ajax methods

Tags: posts, php, ajax

How do I set the `beforesend` option in WordPress AJAX? I want to show loading option.

This is my code:

```
function showmyvideos() { 
    var datas="data";
    var data = {
        action: 'my_vids',
        link: datas  
    }; 
    ajaxurl= "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data,function(response) {

    });

}
```

Comment: This is the wrong way to do ajax within WordPress.  The proper way is documented here: [5 Tips for Using Ajax in WP](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Use `jQuery.ajax()` instead of `jQuery.post()`
2. Use `jQuery.ajaxSetup()` to change the `beforeSend` behavior globally.

**Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257975/using-beforesend-and-complete-with-post**

Answer (score 1):

For posterity.

You can still use `$.ajax()` without having to use `$.ajaxSeteup()`.  All you need to specify is the `type` and make sure it is set to `POST`.

```
$.ajax({

    url: localized_script.ajax_url,  /* Admin ajax url from localized script */
    type: 'POST',  /* Important */
    data: data_object,  /* Data object including 'action' and all post variables */
    beforeSend: function() {
        alert('Before Send');
    },
    success : function(response) {
        alert(response);  /* Response from ajax function */
    },
    complete: function() {
        alert('Complete');
    }
});
```

As you can see, you can set different functions/events for `beforeSend`, `success` and `complete`.

Comment: Lets say I am using $.post, I have the field -  action: [name of the "add_action('wp_ajax_.." ect]. Where do I write it when using $.ajax ?

Comment: You'll set it in the "data_object".  So just before the `$.ajax` call; you'll define `data_object`.  Like, `data_object = { 'action': 'my_action', 'whatever': 1234 };`.

Comment: Or, in the ajax call; set `data:` as `data: { 'action': 'my_action', 'whatever': 1234 },`

Comment: OK, works. 
For some reason I get an error 
`POST http://54.149.xx.xx/wp_admin/admin_ajax.php 404 (Not Found) ` in my console.
Any clue why?

Comment: You have to pass the `admin_ajax.php` url to the script; using localization.  You can try using `url: ajaxurl` (instead of `url: localized_script.ajax_url`) if it's available as a global js variable on the page where you are including your script.  What value are you using for `url:`?

Comment: actually i found my problem.. it's not wp_admin. it's wp-admin. thanks a lot dude! :D

Comment: Awesome.  I missed that in your reply.  Glad you got it working!